# Как не добавлять одинаковые значения в БД + проверять поле?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть запрос:

```
insert into test1 (case_id, component_number, component_name, test_type, test_name, test_description, cft, bisquit, cif, cifle)
values ('1', '018', 'nam_comp', 'pos', 't_01', 'тут текст', '1', 'false', 'false', 'false')
ON CONFLICT (case_id) DO update set
test_description='--новый текст--';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходим совет в том, как переделать таблицу или переписать запрос так, чтобы:
1. при добавления новых записей, одинаковые записи не добавлялись
2. если test_description в новой записи был изменен, необходимо изменить его в старой записи

Comment: приведённый в вопросе запросе делает именно то, о чём вы (по моему разумению) пишете далее.

Answer (score 2):

Запрос выглядит верным. Но может не работать, если у вас нет индекса на уникальность case_id - тогда конфликта нет, и обновления соответственно тоже

Можно добавить с помощью запроса

```
ALTER TABLE test1 ADD UNIQUE (case_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо вопрос сформулирован не так.

Сейчас, он вместо обновления, добавления еще одно значение в БД. Я думаю, это связанно с тем, что **case_id** присваивается автоматически, соответственно проверка отрабатывает не корректно.

Если переформулировать вопрос: как необходимо изменить структуру БД(и/или запрос), чтобы была проверка, скажем по **component_number** и **component_name**(некий составной ключ что ли) и на основе этого проводилась проверка.

Comment: уникальный индекс по полям, если  он есть, то будет ошибка вставки - дубли, а обновление искать по ключу и обновлять его в таблице

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это исправить ситуацию

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
on table_name (column_name1,column_name2 );
```